# CASE Statement to Update Query Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I am using the CASE statement to Update some table data but its giving error incorrect error in WHEN  and THEN Condition.any body can tell whats wrong with this.here is my code,

```
UPDATE TBL_AMOUNT_SETTING 
SET CALCULATED_AMOUNT =
        CASE
           WHEN EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                       FROM TBL_GAME_PRICE_BY_DATE 
                       WHERE GAMEPRICE_DATE = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) 
             THEN 
                (SELECT GAMEPRICE 
                 FROM TBL_GAME_PRICE_BY_DATE 
                 WHERE GAMEID = 10 
                   AND GAMEPRICE_DATE = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
           ELSE NULL
        END
 WHERE REF_GAME_ID = 10
```

Comment: `SET CALCULATED_AMOUNT =
 WHEN `  Where is the `CASE` keyword?

Comment: Please add the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You sql is wrong, you miss the case keyword

The template is as below:

```
select case 
  when exists (
  ...
  ) 
  then ...
  else ...
  end
  where ...
```

Same for update:

```
  update tbl set field =
  case 
  when exists (
  ...
  ) 
  then ...
  else ...
  end
  where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The original problem with your question is missing `Case` keyword in your `update` query.

I think a better do this could be separating the process of your update statement. Since none of your `subquery` is `correlated` you can try this

This is more *readable* then what you are doing

```
DECLARE @gameprice NUMERIC(22, 6) 

IF EXISTS(SELECT Count(*) 
          FROM   tbl_game_price_by_date 
          WHERE  gameprice_date = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) 
  SELECT @gameprice = gameprice 
  FROM   tbl_game_price_by_date 
  WHERE  gameid = 10 
         AND gameprice_date = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()) 

UPDATE tbl_amount_setting 
SET    calculated_amount = @gameprice 
WHERE  ref_game_id = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try it ..**

```
UPDATE tbl_amount_setting 
SET    calculated_amount = ( CASE 
                               WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Count(*) 
                                           FROM   tbl_game_price_by_date 
                                           WHERE  gameprice_date = 
                                                  CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) THEN 
                               (SELECT Max(gameprice) 
                                FROM 
                             tbl_game_price_by_date 
                               WHERE 
                             gameid = tbl_amount_setting.ref_game_id 
                             AND gameprice_date = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) 
                               ELSE NULL 
                             END ) 
WHERE  ref_game_id = 10
```